# How do I get a list of all members in a discord server using the new discord.py version?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently updated my discord.py and it seems some of my older commands are wrong. I need to loop through all the members of a discord server but the old way I did it does not work anymore. Heres my old code.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def missing(ctx, channel : str = None, useDiscordID : bool = False):
    memberlist = []
    for member in message.server.members:
        toAppend = ''
        if "barcode" in [y.name.lower() for y in member.roles]:
            if member.nick is None:
                toAppend = member.name
           else:
                toAppend = member.nick
            if useDiscordID:
                toAppend = f'{str(member)} : {toAppend}'
            memberlist.append(toAppend)
```

this is the part of the code that doesnt work, I dont know what the new way to loop through all the members of the server is since for member in message.server.members: doesnt work anymore. Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you post related exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below snippet will return a generator with every 'Member' the client i.e your bot can see, across all the servers the bot is a member of.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!member'):
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                print(member) # or do whatever you wish with the member detail
```

Comment: doesn't get a full list.

Answer (score 2):

The [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) mentions that `server` has been renamed to `guild`. The correct code should be `message.guild.members`.

Answer (score 0):

They made a security update to this.

And I quote

> **Currently, this requires opting in explicitly via the developer portal as well.** Bots in over 100 guilds will need to apply to Discord for verification.

So firstly you need to go into your developer account and check the **Servers Member Intent** option.

Then call the following:

```
m2 = await g.fetch_members(limit=None).flatten()
```

Where **g** is the retrieved guild object as above.
The above method only returns one user.

I also to be on the safe side did the following at the beginning of my code:

```
# these are the modules imported
from discord.ext.commands.bot import Bot
import discord
# just for reference

discord.MemberCacheFlags.all()

bot = Bot("$")

# the bots flags and the global intents flags set to True
# explicitly.
bot.intents.members=True
Intents.members=True
```

Of interest all of the following will not work, only the api call returns more than 1 member for me.

```
guild.members
bot.get_all_members():
bot.users
```