# Discord.py rewrite get list of members in guild

Tags: discord.py

Just wondering how i would go about getting a list of all current members in a guild and then returning this as a message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of all members in a discord server using the new discord.py version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519760/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-discord-server-using-the-new-discord-py)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the amount of members in specific guild, you can use `len(guild.members)`. If you'd like to get list just use `guild.members`. If you want to send it, it might not work because Discord has max. 2000 characters in one message, but if your server is small then it should be good.

Comment: this actually isn't returning a full list.

Comment: @JohnSohn I've answered this question 2 years ago. A lot has changed since that time, e.g. bot intents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519760/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-discord-server-using-the-new-discord-py/69237608#69237608

Comment: I added the updated answer to this.

Comment: see post and review if you would. you are quite right, so therefore the answer needs updated. I often wonder if someone couldn't add commentary indicating the reasoning behind WHY a change was made, wouldn't that be helpful to understand ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the Member Count Use 
`guild.member_count` where guild is the guild object
and if you want a list, you can iterate over `guild.members`and append them