# Why isn't my member-variable filled if I use discord.utils.get() or discord.utils.find()?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried to find a specific user. I'm using `discord.py` with `discord.utils.get()` but "member" never seems to be filled.

```py
elif "hug" in message.content.lower():
    args = message.content.split(' ')
    if len(args) == 2:
        author = message.author
        member: Member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=args[1])
        if member:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
           await message.channel.send(f'Hey, {member.mention}! {author.mention} sends a lot of hugs and love!')
```

I even tried `discord.utils.find()` in combination with `lambda`:

```py
elif "hug" in message.content.lower():
    args = message.content.split(' ')
    print(str(args[0]) + ' ' + str(args[1]))
    if len(args) == 2:
        author = message.author
        member: Member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: args[1] in m.name, message.guild.members)
        if member:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send(f'Hey, {member.mention}! {author.mention} sends a lot of hugs and love!')
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py rewrite get list of members in guild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633155/discord-py-rewrite-get-list-of-members-in-guild)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I'm trying to get a specific user without using commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you use [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)?

If not implement it like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()  
intents.members = True
```

and then when you instantiate the client give it the intents like following:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why `member` could be `None`. Most common is that you're not using the correct intents. You should pass the `members=True` argument to `discord.Intents()` and enable member intents in [Discord's developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs).

```py
intents = discord.Intents(guids=True, messages=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='.', intents=intents)
```

Just a suggestion. The easiest way to do what you're trying to do, is using the `discord.ext.commands` module.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.commands()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'Hey, {member.mention}! {ctx.author.mention} sends a lot of hugs and love!')
```

Comment: If I use commands in my code, the bot doesn't seem to recognize/reacts to any inputs anymore. 
The following is the code (I don't get any exceptions)
`import discord
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random


client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents(guilds=True, messages=True, members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member):`

Is there another way without using commands?

Comment: Because you have both `bot` and `client`.. you have to choose between them. Try to use the same code you had just, pass your intents object in the client constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `await discord.Guild.fetch_member(member_id)`. Can you please send the exception you had? the discord.utils methods you use might need to be awaited.

Comment: That's the thing: There was no exception. As soon as it checked if member is filled, it returned false..